# Do the stored procedure concepts are existing in core data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

- Do the stored procedure concepts exist in Core Data? If so,
  please share some sample projects links
- I used to see the records are fetched from the entity using the code below. Why not using the SQL query?

  ```
  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  [fetchRequest setEntity: [NSEntityDescription entityForName: @"ServiceTypes" inManagedObjectContext: context]];

  [fetchRequest setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"serviceTypeID == %@", arrData[0]]];

  NSError *error = nil;
  NSArray *fetchResult = [context executeFetchRequest: fetchRequest error:&error];

  if (error) {
      NSLog(@"Unable to execute fetch request.");
      NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
  } else {
      if (fetchResult.count > 0) {
          ServiceTypes object = (ServiceTypes )[fetchResult objectAtIndex: 0];

          if (!boolCkl) {
              [object setValue:arrData[1] forKey:@"code"];
              NSLog(@"Service Type Data Updated");
          } else {
              [context deleteObject: object];
              NSLog(@"Service Type Data Deleted");
          }
      } else {
          ServiceTypes *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"ServiceTypes" inManagedObjectContext: context];
          [object setValue: arrData[0] forKey: @"serviceTypeID"];
          [object setValue: arrData[1] forKey: @"code"];
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: It would be good to do some basic reading on Core Data. It is not a traditional SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the mistaken impression that Core Data is SQL, or at least similar to SQL. It isn't. It can be used to store structured data, but if you try to treat it like SQL you will screw it up badly. Its API is very different. It does not have stored procedures, because it is not SQL. You don't use SQL queries because you are not using SQL. You use code like the sample you presented because that's what Core Data's API looks like.

You would do well to review Apple's [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/), because a full explanation of what it is and how it works would be way too long for a Stack Overflow answer.